# Equality of two functions, given that the product of their difference and its gradient vanishes

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $W \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a open convex set, and $u,v\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R})$
such that $$(w-v)||\nabla v-\nabla w||_2=0 \ in  \ W$$

Can we say that $w=v$?

The problem is that there are $2$ sets of points

$$A_1 = \{x| w=v \}$$ 
$$A_2 = \{x| \nabla v=\nabla w \}$$

But we don't know if the sets are open so we can use basic theorems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing some function multiplied by its gradient suggest using the formula $\nabla (f^2)=2f\,\nabla f$ (which is the chain rule).  So, introduce $f=u-w$, observe that the gradient of $f^2$ is zero, and conclude that $f^2$ is constant. It follows (why?) that $f$ itself is constant.

And that's it: there is no reason why the difference $v-w $ should be identically zero. Being identically constant  fulfills the assumption.

Comment: Thanks :)
does this hold also if I weak the condition for:
$$(w-v)(v_x- w_x)=0 \ in  \ W$$

Comment: @Porufes No. Now you only know that $f^2$ is independent of x. But it may well depend on $y$. For example: $w(x,y)=\sin y$, $v(x,y)=e^y$.

Comment: lol of course xD thanks again, sorry but I have a last one: 

$$(w^2-v^2)||\nabla v-\nabla w||_2=0 \ in  \ W$$

Thanks, anyway I will try it my self

Comment: @Porufes Here you could have either $w^2\equiv v^2$ (which allows $w-v$ to be nonconstant) or $v-w$ is constant. And it's probably possible to have one option somewhere in the domain, and the other option somewhere else. Looks complicated.